# Assigning variables in .tpl to be assigned in included file

Tags: php, smarty

I'm new to working with PHP smarty templating. I set up my original file in .php but I need to convert it to .tpl for a coworker to be able to edit it.

This was my original include statement, where I could manually set a variable for each page:

```
<?php 
    $meta_desc = "<meta name='description' content='This is my page meta description.'>";
    include "includes/document_head.php"; 
?>
```

This is my new code, but the variable isn't being set correctly:

```
{assign "meta_desc" "<meta name='description' content='This is my page meta description.'>"}
{% include file="includes/document_head.php" %}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Whats is the content of the document_head.php ? I recommend to not include a php file inside a smarty template. Anyway, for smarty 2.x you can take a look at include_php http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/de/language.function.include.php.tpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not correct. It should be this:

```
{assign var='meta_desc' value="<meta name='description' content='This is my page meta description.'>"}
{include file="includes/document_head.php"}
```

Comment: It all blows up when I don't include the % in the include statement.

Comment: Update: Just discovered that a decision was made within my org (before I joined) that our smarty tags must be wrapped with {% %} - so your code is correct!

Comment: @pork-chop ohk great job by you.